# How to get image and show in my page angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-web-api, file-upload, angular6

I'm saving image from uploader into database so it's working perfect for me but the question is if I want to show that image in my website so how can I show them and also image path should be shown like `src="http://www.example.com/image.png"`.
Please give me any example/solution for it.

TS

```
imageUrl: string = "/assets/img/default-image.png";
  fileToUpload: File = null;
  constructor(private imageService: ImageUploadService) { }

  handleInputFile(file: FileList){
    this.fileToUpload = file.item(0);
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (event:any) => {
      this.imageUrl = event.target.result;
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.fileToUpload);
  }

  OnSubmit(Caption,Image){
    this.imageService.postFile(Caption.value, this.fileToUpload).subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log("Done");
        Caption.value = "";
        Image.value = "";
      }
    );
  }
```

Service.Ts

```
postFile(caption: string, fileToUpload: File){
    const endpoint = 'http://localhost:3343/api/UploadImage';
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append("Image", fileToUpload, fileToUpload.name);
    formData.append("Caption", caption);
    return this.http.post(endpoint,formData);
  }
```

HTML

```
<form #imageForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="OnSubmit(Caption,Image)">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <input type="text" #Caption ngModel name="Caption" id="Caption">
          <label for="Caption">Caption</label>
        </div>
        <img [src]="imageUrl" style="width:200px;height:200px;">
        <input type="file" #Image accept="Image/*" (change)="handleInputFile($event.target.files)">
        <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit">Submit
          <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
        </button>
      </form>
```

Comment: I made a demo in my answer, you can take a look

Answer (score 4):

I'm sharing my code from my project. In this example,

I have an API that im calling it with `customerNumber` which returns me `blob` type data. And I returning this data to my component from service, In my component side I'm taking that data as blob and converting it to `Image` type with using `this.createImageFromBlob` function. And finally I'm showing that image on template side by using `imageToShow.photo` variable in `<img [src]="imageToShow.photo">` tag.

**My service.ts side,**

```
  getCustomerImages(customerNumber: number, type: string): Observable<File> {
    let result: Observable<any> = this.http
      .get(`${this.apiBaseUrl}csbins/Customer/${customerNumber}/images`, { responseType: "blob" });
    return result;
  }
```

**My component.ts side,**

```
  getCustomerImages() {
    this.isImageLoading = true;
    this.getCustomerImagesSubscription = this.getCustomerService.getCustomerImages(this.refNo).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.createImageFromBlob(data);
        this.isImageLoading = false;
      },
      error => {
        this.isImageLoading = false;
      });
  }
```

and convert blob to image here in your component,

```
  createImageFromBlob(image: Blob) {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener("load",
      () => {
          this.imageToShow.photo = reader.result;
      },
      false);

    if (image) {
      if (image.type !== "application/pdf")
        reader.readAsDataURL(image);
    }
  }
```

**and my template.html side,**

```
          <ng-template [ngIf]="imageTypeShow">
              <ng-template [ngIf]="imageToShow.photo">
                  <img [src]="imageToShow.photo" class="img-thumbnail" *ngIf="!isImageLoading;">
              </ng-template>
          </ng-template>
```

Feel free to ask if you don't understand any point.

Answer (score 0):

This is way I used to read image from Database.

Create method in service to get image from DB

```
getImage(path: string){
        return  this.http.get('/api/image?name=' + encodeURIComponent(path));
}
```

Use service in component
Add `private sanitizer: DomSanitizer` to constructor component

```
 this.imageService.getImage(this.path).
                subscribe((data: any) => {

                            let objectURL = 'data:image/png;base64,' + data.Image;
             this.image = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(objectURL);

            }, (err) => {
                console.log('HttpErrorResponse error occured.');
            });
```

Display in HTML file

```
<img id="myimage" [src]='image' >
```

Update:
I created a demo display image from base64 format that stored in json file.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/display-image-from-api